# Fb.UI Dialogs are displaying in Popups instead of an iframe (part 2)

Tags: javascript, facebook

This is related to this issue: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7246169/fb-ui-dialogs-are-displaying-in-popups-instead-of-an-iframe

Thanks to the help of OffBySome I was able to get my various FB.ui dialog boxes showing up happily in an iframe rather than popping up unfortunately what I'm seeing now is that the dialog will appear but the throbber sits loading forever. Is anyone else seeing the behavior I described in these two posts or is there something further I must do to get the FB.ui dialogs working properly? Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I wanted to add to this that ultimately it proved to be nothing wrong with Facebook. Apparently something was set improperly in my FFox profile and resetting it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing Facebook recently made a change that is causing this issue as other are having this same problem.